# Download progress bar of pdf streaming

Tags: java, ajax, pdf, jquery

When i am streaming large pdf files it takes more than 10 sec and i want to display a progression bar that indicates the percentage of the file that has been downloaded.
I don't want just display an animated gif, i need to indicate the progression of the pdf download.

I am trying to implement the download progress bar while streaming a pdf into a browser (IE or FF).
I am using a servlet that displays the pdf stream through jquery calls.
My server side is coded in java.

Any help on this ?

Comment: What do you mean by stream? Are you linking to it thru a <a> tag and generate it on the fly? Or how do you stream it?

Comment: I have a stream of bytes to display Simon

Answer (score 0):

**Outline suggestion:**

When serving the file:

- Write bytes to out in chunks, maybe a few kb at a time and loop until EOF.
- Update progress in the user session.

(Example of dividing the output into chunks: http://www.coderanch.com/t/363817/Servlets/java/file-download-servlet-showing-progress )

Implement an AJAX server-side call, returning the current progress. (Depending on what you want jQuery can for instance retrieve JSON for the client-side progress bar script).

Comment: Is there any sample of the ajax progress bar integrated with the byte to out in chunks.